# merging two tables with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, plsql, toad

I'm newbie to sql.

There are two different tables with same columns and assume that Name unique.

**TABLE_A**

```
Name  | AGE
-----------
Toby  |  2
Milo  |  1
Achmed|  3
```

**TABLE_B**

```
Name  | AGE
-----------
Milo  |  2
```

TABLE_B is my superior table, If TABLE_B name value contains in TABLE_A, than TABLE_B's value should be selected. RESULT is shown below.

RESULT is not a table, the result of query.

**RESULT**

```
Name  | AGE
-----------
Toby  |  2
Milo  |  2
Achmed|  3
```

I have already solve this problem on the programming side, but I'm curries about the sql query to get this result.

TSQL or PLSQL doesnt matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FULL JOIN` to get all rows from both tables and `COALESCE` to give precedence to Table_B if Name exists in both tables.

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE (b.Name, a.Name) as Name
  ,COALESCE (b.Age, a.Age) as Age
FROM Table_A a
FULL JOIN Table_B b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b1ca/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can "fuse" both results using a union like this

```
SELECT Name, AGE FROM TABLE_A
UNION
SELECT Name, AGE FROM TABLE_B
ORDER BY Name;
```

The SQL statement selects all the different Names and Ages  from the "TABLE_A" and the "TABLE_B" tables.

Comment: This will not work as desired - as it will return two rows for both `Milo|1` and `Milo|2`

Answer (score 1):

You could also eliminate any duplicates while using union, I think this would be faster than a full join:

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Table_B
UNION
SELECT Name, Age FROM Table_A WHERE TABLE_A.NAME NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM Table_B)
ORDER BY Name;
```